# How to implement a growing list

Tags: java, multithreading, list

I am attempting to iterate through the same data, but want to only load the data if it is necessary. I also want to reuse the fetched data in multiple, concurrent, iterators.

Is there an object, or a pattern, that would allow me to create an underlying data that has an opportunity to fetch more data if it runs out, but uses the same fetched data across multiple instances? The list should be able to be used concurrently. I happen to be using Java.

I have currently created an Iterator that returns values that can be used, if it runs out of data in its buffer, it goes and looks up more data to be returned. Unfortunately, this means that if there are multiple instances of the object, it will process the data once for each instance.

If I use a LinkedList I am concerned about ConcurrentModificationError.

UPDATE: The answer below does discuss a valid means to implement this, but I have had a lot of problems caused by the concept in general (non-standard, confuses implementors, benefits not worth the confusion). While I continue to believe this is an interest and valuable avenue, it can be problematic. As ever, before asking "how" to do something, you should ask "if" you should do it at all.

Comment: Should data ever be removed from the structure?

Comment: Could you use a `Hazelcast` map, with a `MapLoader`?

Comment: No data will be removed (until I release the object)

Comment: What you need looks somewhat like Scala's Stream.

Comment: In hindsight, I was attempting to implement a "stream" concept, but one that I could iterate multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it.

- Create a class that implements `Iterable`.
- The class needs a private variable of type `ArrayList` which is initialized to an empty list.
- The class needs a `fill` method that fetches one or more entries from the source of data and adds them to the end of the private list.
- The class needs a `noMore` flag that is set when the `fill` method can't get any more data.
- The class needs an `iterator()` method to deliver new instances of an inner `Iterator` class:

  - Each iterator needs a private index ... and position in the parent classes list.
  - The `hasNext` method tests the index against the parent classes list size().  If they are the same it calls `fill`.  If the `noMore` flag is set, it returns `false`.
  - The `next` method ... well you get the idea.

All of this needs to be properly synchronized ...

---

This approach avoids the problem of `ConcurrentModificationExceptions` by hiding the private list, and not using an `Iterator` on it.  The actual iterators would use `get(int)` on the private list to fetch elements.

Note: this approach won't work predictably if the private list is exposed allowing other code to update or iterate the list in the normal way.

Comment: The devil is often in the details but that sounds like it would work.

Comment: Good answer. I had to read your answer twice to fully understand what you were saying. I was suggesting improvements that you had already mentioned. The devil *is* definitely in the details on this one.

Comment: `Iterator` and `Iterable` are not the same thing. This has been a thought experiment that reinforced that concept for me. The thing that crawls the list, is not the same as the list itself, your answer emphasizes that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood your question right, but does CopyOnWriteArrayList: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html suit your purpose?

Comment: Interesting, but not right. I am looking as this would mean that any growth of the underlying list would not be accessible to other instances of the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Why not synchronization??

```
 Collection c = Collections.synchronizedCollection(myCollection);
```

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned collection when iterating over it:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedCollection(java.util.Collection)

Comment: I don't think this will work because I would like the returned data to be processed concurrently, synchronization would force serial data access.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use an Object Pool? I do not know what you are trying to do with what kind of data, but I believe that with some modifications the object pool may suit your needs.

A link to a sample object pool
http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/object_pool/java

Comment: I love ObjectPools, but it is definitely not right in this case. The data is a list of webpages and I want every page to be accessed by every thread, and there is no reason they shouldn't do so concurrently.